# Forward to configurable product when opening simple product

Tags: magento

I have a Magento shop with 2 simple products

- Great Red Cup
- Great Blue Cup

and a configurable product

- Great Cup

with those cups assigned.

The Red and Blue cups are visible in the search.

If the use clicks one of those simple products, the configurable product should be opened instead, but the right color should be preselected.

I am aware that a simple product can be assigned to multiple configurable products, so I would log an exception if two matching configurable products are found an just take the first one.

I think I have to catch the predispatch event of catalog/product/view and somehow replace the simple product by the configurable one.

How can I now pre-configure the right simple product one?

Is there an elegant solution for this?

Comment: Starting point: http://gabrielsomoza.com/magento/getting-a-products-parent-id-in-magento/ http://www.webcatch.co.uk/blog/index.php/2010/04/01/magento-qa-how-to-redirect-from-simple-product-to-configurable-product/

Comment: Is it mandatory to have the simple products visible in search? Simple products part of configurable usually are not visible individually.

Comment: @FlorinelChis Yes it is. The idea is that you can find also "Red Cup" in the search if you want one.

Comment: add all the colors in a new attribute that is searchable but not visible :)

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution:

1. register observer on `controller_action_predispatch_catalog_product_view`
2. check if we have a simple product with a parent that is a configurable product
3. create a array that contains the configuration data of the simple product
4. pass this data to `Mage::helper('catalog/product_view')->prepareAndRender()` (third parameter)
5. stop dispatching by setting the `FLAG_NO_DISPATCH` on the front action

Full code is available in the [Mestrona_ForwardToConfigurable module on github](https://github.com/Mestrona/Mestrona_ForwardToConfigurable).

Comment: Thanks for this.  I took a different approach for my client's requirements and wanted to share in case anyone finds it useful https://github.com/eyemaginesrobbins/Magento-SimpleRedirect

Comment: Alex, that works perfectly - thanks! @Steve, your Magento-SimpleRedirect works as well, but doesn't retain the attributes of the simple product (which may be the way you built it of course)

Answer (score 1):

To preselect a simple product in a configurable product, the address of a simple product should look like this for example:

> **`/mona-pullover-hoodlie.html#143=167&93=53`**

where

`/mona-pullover-hoodlie.html` - configurable product URL

`143`, `93` - attribute IDs

`167`, `53` - option IDs.

In order to change the URL of simple products, you can create a [Plugin (Interceptor)](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html%5D) for **`Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::getProductUrl()`**, where to generate the URL as in the example above.

Product selection using URL parameters from example above is already implemented in Magento out of the box.

---

I made `VCT Simple Product URl` module on Magento Marketplace that solves this problem with the choice of the first configurable product if there are several.

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to redirect to the configurable product if the simple products meets somes requirements :

- have a new attribute "should_redirect_to_parent" to True (optionnal)
- have at least a parent product (for that point, I let you follow the link of Alex)

ps: if you don't want to do a parent product lookup you could add a new attribute like "redirect_sku" or "redirect_product_id" in order to directly make a redirection on that product

For the redirection you should use the event `catalog_controller_product_init_after` and if the two previous conditions match you redirect the user to the configurable product.

ps: for performance optimisation, you could use instead the `catalog_controller_product_init_before` which would save an expansive and useless Product::load() but it requires that you build custom SQL queries to search for a parent product

Tell if you want some code examples

Comment: Thank you. That is a good start. The other challenge is to already configure the configurable product with the correct action. Actually I think I will try to use similar code as in  `Mage_Checkout_CartController::configureAction()`

Comment: I think I can call `$product->setPreconfiguredValues()`

Comment: The problem with the product_init events is, that if I hook in there and want to render another product, that this causes a recursion, because initProduct is called again. So I actually used the predispatch hook now in my module.

Comment: In that case, you shouldn't "render" a new product but "redirect" to it.

Comment: I think it is not possible to redirect and pre-select the right options. Anyways - I have found a solution and will publish it soon.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible ?  Anyways, I hope you thought of the SEO side, if you don't redirect to another url (with proper headers), search engines could see your pages as duplicated content.